# Woocommerce списание остатков через аднинку

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Где-то неделю назад обнаружился глюк с WooCommerce. При добавлении товара в заказ через админку этот товар перестал сниматься с остатка. Грешу на обновление плагина, т.к. мной в код никаких изменений (касающихся снятия товара с остатков, по крайней мере) не вносилось. Версия WP - 5.4, WooCommerce - 4.4.1. Самое интересное, что такая функция раньше работала.

И второй вопрос: если не получиться обнаружить и исправить причину этого, как программно можно заставить WC выполнять эту функцию? Например, что повесить на обработку нажатия кнопки "Обновить" заказа? В общем, куда копать?

Comment: Ну и что, что вы не вносили изменений в код. Если у вас код сделан был через прямой доступ к базе - то всё, ловите проблемы. WC сейчас активно уходит на свои таблицы.

Comment: @KAGG Design Все изменения, которые вносились, были через хуки. И их было штук 10 всего. Причём конкретно WooCommerce касались только парочка. Добавлял кастомные поля для товаров.

Comment: Трудно тогда предположить причину. В ошибку WooCommerce я не верю.

Comment: @ KAGG Design В ошибку я тоже не верю. Хотя на просторах нашёл такое, якобы, официальное заявление: "By default, product inventory does not decrease when an order is created manually. It’s possible to force a stock reduction but this would require some custom coding." То есть, это не баг, а фича. Но мне нужно от неё избавиться.

Comment: В вопросе ни слова о ручном заказе, и почему "глюк" обнаружился только неделю назад. А до этого, значит, всё работало?

Comment: @ KAGG Design Со слов заказчика, всё работало. Сам тогда не проверял. Проверил сейчас, товар действительно с остатка не снимается.